# sharing internet from PC to PC

Tags: connection, ethernet

I am trying to share wifi internet from my pc to another pc with ethernet cable. I set sharing wifi and checked the allow other network. And set the IP on the Ethernet LAN to static mode at **192.168.0.1** On the other PC I set it to static mode also at **192.168.0.2** and gateway at **192.168.0.1**. but it says no internet access. can anyone provide a solution?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use "Sharing" in network options.

Comment: I already checked sharing options

Comment: DNS settings on 192.168.0.2 ?  
Try 8.8.8.8 DNS on 192.168.0.2.

Comment: I've tried using DNS 8.8.8.8 still can't connect

Comment: please provide output of
`ipconfig /all` on both hosts